# Is there any max limits for the transactions that can happen in a network in Hyperledger?

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am new to Hyperledger.
Where is the transaction data stored?

In the disk or any kind of db?

How many transactions can be stored in the Hyperledger node where it is stored?

Is there a max limit?

Is there a estimate on how fast a Hyperledger transactions grows?

What are the steps to be taken once it reaches the max limit?﻿

Answer (score 2):

It might be worth investigating the new Hyperledger Caliper incubator project to answer your performance questions. I expect that the answers will depend a lot on what you are trying to achieve and Caliper should let you run tests with your own blockchain network to get results specific to your own scenarios.

There are more details on the project page and announcement blog post if you think it might be useful:

- https://www.hyperledger.org/projects/caliper
- https://www.hyperledger.org/blog/2018/03/19/measuring-blockchain-performance-with-hyperledger-caliper

Comment: Thanks James. Has anybody shared a benchmark for any of the sample network? To get a ballpark figure. Need to know what all are the decisive factors. I was assessing about a production deployment of a network, created using hyperleger composer. Is there any documentation available for that? Basically I need to know the production installation steps, the system requirements like number of cores, hard disk size, memory etc. If there are multiple participants with their own hardware resources how will be the setup?

Comment: I know there's some work underway to publish some performance reports for Composer but I don't think they're available yet. Nick Lincoln is adding Composer support to Caliper as part of that, https://github.com/nklincoln/caliper-1 (I'll update the answer with a link when any report does get published.)

Answer (score 0):

Where is the transaction data stored? In the disk or any kind of db?
Transaction data is stored on the channel(there is one Blockchain ledger per channel) and the current state called as world state is stored in levedb by default OR couchdb (if you explicitly configure it).

How many transactions can be stored in the Hyperledger node where it is stored? Is there a max limit?
After you log in to peer you can view the channel with your 'channelname' at the following path
/var/hyperledger/production/ledgersData/chains/chains/channelname
There is no limit to number of transactions channel can store. However you can put the limit on number of transactions that goes into a single block.

Is there a estimate on how fast a Hyperledger transactions grows?
Transactions are executed and recorded on channel (or blockchain), as a result of which blockchain grows. How fast the blockchain grows depends on the frequency and number of transactions.

What are the steps to be taken once it reaches the max limit?
There is no upper limit to the size of ledger/blockchain other than the hard-disk size.